# Calculating adjacency matrix from UMAP connectivity?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, knn, adjacency-matrix, tsne

From knn-graph, we can calculate adjency matrix using scipy package as follows:

```
ids = df.index
knn = kneighbors_graph(df.values, n_neighbors, metric = metric, 
                                mode = 'connectivity').toarray()
knn = pd.DataFrame(knn, columns = ids, index = ids)
```

This gives us an adjacency matrix for KNN-neighbor?

Similarly, how can we get a connectivity adjacency matrix from UMAP and t-SNE algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

in both `umap_learn` and `cuml`(vers. >22.06), `UMAP.fit()` returns a `.graph_`, which is the adjacency output